# How to call Async stored procedure calls in C# in a generic way without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stored-procedures

I would like to refactor many stored procedure calls that all have a very similar pattern to use a generic method. I'm still new to async programming so would like some advice on the impact of my intention.

**Unfortunately I would not be able to use EF**

Existing example:

```
var myModel = new Model();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Some Connection String"))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("Some Stored Procedure Name", connection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();

                    //Code Building a list of params

                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                           //Code Building myModel
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return myModel;
```

What I would like to achieve is a method in which you pass the stored procedure name and a list of parameters, and it would return an object that I can iterate though to retrieve the values I need.

Are there any considerations I need to be aware of regarding OpenAsync/ReadAsync? Also what object would be best to return data from the reader?

Comment: Why not use a DataAdapter and then put results into a datatable. You will then always be returning a DataTable.